# How to print out a classes' var fields in toString without override?

Tags: scala, tostring

I have the following class:

```
case class Info(ticker: String, countryCode: String) {

  var companyName: String = _
  var marketPlace: String = _
  var countryName: String = _
  var tierId: Int = _
}
```

When I do info.toString, it only prints out the ticker and country code. How can I get the other fields to print out without manually overriding the toString method?

Comment: Why are you opposed to overriding `toString`?

Comment: i just want to avoid adding additional lines of code...

Comment: at the expense of setting default fields to `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just provide the extra fields as entries in the case class, but mark them as `var`:

```
case class Info(
  ticker: String,
  countryCode: String,
  var companyName: String = null,
  var marketPlace: String = null,
  var countryName: String = null,
  var tierId: Int = 0
)
```

That adds them to the generated `toString`:

```
scala> Info("TK", "US")
res1: Info = Info(TK,US,null,null,null,0)
```

but you can still mutate the ones you need to:

```
scala> res1.companyName = "Cool Co."
res1.companyName: String = Cool Co.

scala> res1
res2: Info = Info(TK,US,Cool Co.,null,null,0)
```

Comment: The other way does too - `_` in this case translates into `null` for the `String` type and `0` for the `Int` type.